# How can I prove that a curve with constant angular momentum is plane curve?

Tags: vectors, plane-curves

If

$$L(t) := X(t) \times mX'(t) = v$$

and $v$ is an constant vector, $X(t)$ curve is a plane curve. How do I prove it?

Comment: Well, how *do* you prove it?

Comment: You might look at $L'(t) = X(t) \times mX''(t) =0$ which means $X''(t)$ is collinear with $X(t)$.  Will say more if your question stays open.  (You midht consider adding some context.)  Cheers!